# Cucumber + Protractor - timed out error while executing the steps

Tags: selenium, protractor, cucumber, chai

I am using cucumber and protractor to write behavioural driven tests.My scenarios and all the steps will pass but at the end it will show timed out error. The homepage will get loaded for the first step and later it will not perform any steps described in the steps definition file. Once the page is loaded it should click on the tabs. I have mentioned these steps in step definition file.But these steps are not executed and it will show all the steps passed in the console. I followed this link for reference https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-protractor-and-cucumber

This is the error message

[image]

Please find the sample code below.

```
//sample.feature
Feature: The Dashboard has 2 tabs, Statistics and Results 

Scenario: I  want to have 2 tabs with Displayed text "Statistics" and "Results" on the homepage 

Given I go to Dashboard homepage
And I click on the "#/results" 
Then the Results page is displayed
And I click on the "#/Statistics" tab
Then the Statistics page is displayed

//menu.steps.js
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;

module.exports = function() {
  this.Given(/^I go to Dashboard homepage$/, function() {
  browser.get('http://localhost:8100/#/');
  browser.waitForAngular();
  });

    this.Then(/^I click on the "([^"]*)"$/,function(arg1){
    element(by.css('[href="#/results"]')).click();    
   });

    this.Then(/^the results page is displayed$/, () => {
    browser.get('http://localhost:8100/#/results'); 
});
    this.When(/^I click on the "([^"]*)" tab$/, function(arg1) {
    element(by.css('[href="#/statistics"]')).click();     
    });


    this.Then(/^the statistics page is displayed$/,  () =>{         
    browser.get('http://localhost:8100/#/statistics');  
    });

//cucumber.conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'custom',  // set to "custom" instead of cucumber.
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'), 
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['test/e2e/cucumber/*.feature'],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox',

},
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100/#/',


   // cucumber command line options
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['test/e2e/cucumber/*.steps.js'],  // require step definition files before executing features
    tags: [],                      // <string[]> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression
    strict: true,                  // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
    format: ["pretty"],            // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format, optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)
    dryRun: false,                 // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
    compiler: []                   // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
  },

 onPrepare: function () {
    browser.manage().window().maximize(); // maximize the browser before executing the feature files
  },

  resultJsonOutputFile: './test/e2e/results.json'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using CucumberJS, you can choose to use **callbacks** or **promises**. In your code, you didn't use one of them. Below, you will find an example of your steps how you can use promises, of callbacks.

Be aware of the fact that you if you implement one of the 2 solutions, your tests could still fail, but that has more to do with the test implementation instead of the solution for callbacks / promises

```js
// With promises
module.exports = function() {
  this.Given(/^I go to Dashboard homepage$/, function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:8100/#/');
    return browser.waitForAngular();
  });

  this.Then(/^I click on the "([^"]*)"$/, function(arg1) {
    return element(by.css('[href="#/results"]')).click();
  });

  this.Then(/^the results page is displayed$/, () => {
    return browser.get('http://localhost:8100/#/results');
  });
  this.When(/^I click on the "([^"]*)" tab$/, function(arg1) {
    return element(by.css('[href="#/statistics"]')).click();
  });

  this.Then(/^the statistics page is displayed$/, () => {
    return browser.get('http://localhost:8100/#/statistics');
  });
}

// With callbacks
module.exports = function() {
  this.Given(/^I go to Dashboard homepage$/, function(done) {
    browser.get('http://localhost:8100/#/');
    browser.waitForAngular().then(done);
  });

  this.Then(/^I click on the "([^"]*)"$/, function(arg1, done) {
    element(by.css('[href="#/results"]')).click().then(done);
  });

  this.Then(/^the results page is displayed$/, (done) => {
    browser.get('http://localhost:8100/#/results').then(done);
  });
  this.When(/^I click on the "([^"]*)" tab$/, function(arg1, done) {
    element(by.css('[href="#/statistics"]')).click().then(done);
  });

  this.Then(/^the statistics page is displayed$/, (done) => {
    browser.get('http://localhost:8100/#/statistics').then(done);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey!! With promises - I get Timed out error `function timed out after 5000 milliseconds` and with callbacks I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'notify' of undefined
`

Comment: The reason why you get the `5000 milliseconds` error is that CucumberJS is defaulted to a timeout of `5000 milliseconds`, please read [this ](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/1.x/docs/support_files/timeouts.md) to fix this.
Hope it helps

Comment: The timeout worked for only first step `this.Given(/^I go to Dashboard homepage$/,{timeout: 60 * 1000}, function() {
return browser.get('http://localhost:8100/#/');
  });
` and for the second step same way I added the timeout but it failed showing timed out error as shown in the above image at the start

Comment: As said in my solution,  the solution fixes your initial problem, you now got some scripting errors.

Comment: okay thanks. How do I fix these scripting errors? Is it problem with my steps? My steps are very simple - Open homepage and click on the two tabs displayed.

Comment: Can you please paste the html, of give an example project on git?

Comment: This is how html element looks in chrome browser console
        `<li><a ng-reflect-href="#/statistics" href="#/statistics">Statistics</a>
      </li>`