# How to fix "Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 60000 milliseconds"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, protractor, cucumber

I'm working on automations tests with the framework protractor-cucumberjs. And I have a problem when I run my test, especially when I try to interact with the DOM like click on a button.

I have already check on the web if there is a solution for this problem but I tried everything (increase defaultTimeOut), it was in vain.

I writed my cucumber steps in TypeScript and I use babel to convert ts to ES5 because I use this version of NodeJs : 7.4.0

Here is my cucumber steps in TS :

```
When('L\'utilisateur coche {string} sur la checkbox', async(string) => {
    await element(by.id(string)).click();
});
```

And here is the convert ts in ES5 :

```js
cucumber_1.When('L\'utilisateur coche {string} sur la checkbox', function (string) { return __awaiter(_this, void 0, void 0, function () {
    return __generator(this, function (_a) {
        switch (_a.label) {
            case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, protractor_1.element(protractor_1.by.id(string)).click()];
            case 1:
                _a.sent();
                return [2 /*return*/];
        }
    });
}); });
```

And the output is :

`Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 60000 milliseconds`

I don't understand why, I even took a screenshot of the chrome during the tests and I can see that the rendering is completely finish.

Thanks for the help.

Alexandre BOUDET

**EDIT :**

Here is my new tests :

```js
Given('L\'utilisateur se déplace sur la page {string}', function (string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return browser.get(browser.baseUrl + string);
});

When('L\'utilisateur coche {string} sur la radiobox', function (string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return element(by.id(string)).click();
});

When('L\'utilisateur ajoute {string} dans le champ {string}', function (string, string2) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return element(by.id(string2)).sendKeys(string1);
});

When('L\'utilisateur clique sur le bouton {string}', function (string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return element(by.id(string)).click();
});

When('L\'utilisateur sélectionne le logiciel LAD qui a pour code {string}', function (string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return element(by.id(string)).click();
});

When('L\'utilisateur sélectionne le type de messagerie {string}', function (string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return element(by.id(string)).click();
});

When('L\'utilisateur coche {string} sur la checkbox', function (string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return element(by.id(string)).click();
});

Then('Le bouton {string} est enabled', function (string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return expect(element(by.id(string)).isEnabled()).to.equal(true);;
});
```

And I have the same problem (function time out)

Comment: Perhaps you need to return a promise from the step definition function.

Comment: Hum, you mean : return await element(by.id(string)).click();

Comment: Yep, could be even without `await`, just `return element(by.id(string)).click();`

Comment: Thanks for the tips but it doesn't work, I have the same problem of unresolved promise.

Comment: Did you tried to remove `await` AND `async` ? Here is a similar topic, btw : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647510/cucumber-protractor-timed-out-error-while-executing-the-steps

Comment: Yeah I transformed my js file without async/await and the problem persist.